# HTML app -- with gmail like select menu

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an Html based study notebook. Where we can see the :--

```
Vegitable
Meat
Motor Vehical
Cloths
```

I need to add a feature to my html page (feature like Gmail Mobile Phone app) , if i take my mouse to the left of screen 
it shows a menu to select the vegitable, Motor vehical etc.

Means feature like Gmail mobile app, where we can select the sent mail, primary mail, social mail & outbox mail from a menu appering from left of the screen.

Is it possible with HTML ?

I need to add this feature to my HTML page. Please suggest how to do this.

Code :--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">

<head>
<title>My item list </title>
<style>
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
.input {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
.input input {
    display: block;
}
.imgtxt {
    margin: 0;
    font-family:arial;
    color:#DDDFED;
    font-size:15px;
}
#images {
    background-color: grey;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
div.scrollable {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


div.scrollableMenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

div.scrollableCenter {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#center {
    background-color:#292B3B;
    position:absolute;
    top:115px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:20px;
}
#fotter {
    background-color:#CC99FF;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body >
    <div id="images" class="scrollable">
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTBRnn9Aqx74JvKyJ7Z5ydbXXuj8cIDVuOdJZUxb02Q2LWfJGP" onclick="alert('clicked')" title="Room one" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Normal Vegitable</p>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="http://www.boldsky.com/img/2013/03/19-greenveggies.jpg" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Green Vegitable</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="center" class="scrollableCenter">
        <div >
            <input type="image" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMPmp8aVaovrd3AGj1_hL_GEXX1M4DJ-TTMJ34Vr622XeY_usu" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">brinjal</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

        <div >
            <input type="image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Cauliflower.JPG" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">cauliflower</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

        <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJgt4i9ph9uQsS3JV940PBg-kwN1kkrKbC6FLYI6UhbxucEb91" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">tomato</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

    <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-mwuxaqQeHXjoZzPUoee9Rvg8Jq-eCvo8H0EgEtapjfr6U4E3" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">ladyfinger</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

    <div >
            <input type="image" src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRxXUO2stKHLyET_rXpxOuLp67qc1IzlBcJGke5jYoGPeRZpnO" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">radish</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

    <div >
            <input type="image" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2zCeG621TSX1YmcsT9DPLaQJkdVwdYk_n-eWECCa8NTtXR0LFeQ" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">ginger</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fotter">List of Items</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Gmail App :--
[image]

Comment: the answer is "Yes it is", but what is your actual question

Comment: I need to add this feature to my HTML page. Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: So you are showing some html. What is that not doing now that it should be doing?

Comment: Maybe use the CSS pseudo class ":hover" to show the content and increase the width of a small left border when hovered

Comment: I really don't think its possible using just html and css. Some javascript and jquery methods can solve this easily

Comment: @mplungjan at present i do not have any menu to select item from. So i need programing help.

Comment: Any suggestion how to get it working ..?

Comment: @M.S. Can you show some jsfiddle example how to do this .. ?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality that you need is called `Drawer`. [This drawer plugin](http://git.blivesta.com/drawer/left/) should be able to help you.

Download the plugin here: https://github.com/blivesta/drawer

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this there are various ways:

1. Use jquery plugins such as:

   http://jpanelmenu.com/

   http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-sliding-sidebar-panel-plugins/

   http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

   http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/

   http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/  etc.
2. Use CSS framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) etc.

   http://pivotallabs.com/html5-facebook-style-sliding-menu-using-twitter-bootstrap-collapse/   - example show menu made with help of bootstrap

   http://jsfiddle.net/Osis/Mns8q/ - example show menu made with
      help of bootstrap

   http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/off-canvas-sidebar

   http://jsbin.com/seqola/2/edit?html,css,js,output

For bootstrap you have to use following code in head

```
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <meta charset=utf-8 />
 <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
```

3. You can use [jQuery Mobile panel](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/panel/). Just suggestion I know you are not using JQM